# How can I send select2 value to my Java code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I am developing a Jira Plugin (Servlet & Rest) which is shows project names in a select2 list and when user selects a selection, my datatable will show Issue keys and summaries of them.

The problem is I need the selection of my select list in my Java code. Somehow, I need to send it the selection value inside my Java. Some of my friend give me an advice about using "jQuery.ajax" but I couldn't figure it out how I can do it.

Here is my select2 js code:

```
AJS.$('#select2-example2').on('click', function () {
 console.log("Selected value: " + AJS.$(this).auiSelect2('val')); });
```

And I think I need some REST Endpoint in my Java code and I don't know how I can do it either. I need your help about that thing as well.

I know I asked so much questions but I'm new at plugin development stuff and I know I should have develop myself way too much. Thanks already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the code

```js
$('#button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let value = $('#sel').val();
  //send the data with post
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: value
    })
    .done(function(data) {
             // if post status is 200
         // code here
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

```html
<select name="select" id="sel">
  <option value="first" selected>1</option>
  <option value="second">2</option>
</select>

<button id="button">Click</button>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```